# Navigation Buttons no whitespace underneathe

Tags: html, css, image, navigation

Really want to try have no whitespace between my nav buttons and the image below. Cant imagine it being too difficult but this has got me having a mind block!
This is what I want to achieve with the arrow showing where I want the change to happen:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
        <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Body Metrix">
        </div>
      </div>

            <div class="large-6 columns" id="nav-btn">
              <ul class="navigation">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="not"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="not"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="not"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12  columns">
      <div class="kickstart"><img src="img/kick-start.png">
        <p class="getfit"><img src="img/get-fit.png"></p>
        <p class="home-text"> BodyMetrix Personal Training is a new company, based in South London, aiming to bring one-on-one training sessions and personalised exercise and nutrition plans. </p>
        <p class="get-contact"><img src="img/get-contact-btn.png"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
ul .navigation {
    margin-left: 2.5px;

    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}
.navigation li {

    display: inline-block;

}
.navigation .active {
    padding:0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #8fbe4e;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navigation .active a {
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.navigation .not{

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

}
.navigation .not a {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7f8183;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navigation li a:hover {    
    color: #50B748;
}

#wrapper {
    background-image: url("../img/home-img.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    width: 100% !important;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a margin between the `ul` tag and the image below. Therefore you can solve the problem like so:

```
.navigation { margin:0; }
```

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/gKC79/3/)**

### So why was the margin there in the first place?

You see, by default `ul` tags have a top-margin and bottom-margin, which you can see for example if you inspect a `ul` tag with Chrome:

```
ul, menu, dir {                                             user agent stylesheet

    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;

}
```

Comment: Hi again, wondering if you could help again with a similar problem. You've solved the gap at the bottom now how do I get rid of the gap of top? There is a <hr> above and i just want the gap to be closed.