# Unwanted Whitespace

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I asked a similar question recently about navigation buttons and having whitespace below and above and it was answered very well. Here is the question [Navigation Buttons no whitespace underneathe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832756/navigation-buttons-no-whitespace-underneathe)

Basically now I have whitespace above the button and I need it closed.

Also I would like the text in the buttons to be center both vertically and horizontally.

[image]

Js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ygfX7/4/
Any ideas?

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-9 small-12 columns" id="contact-top-pad">
        <p>
            <span class="contact-top">Phone</span><span class="smaller">- 0757776856</span> 
            <span class="contact-top">Email</span><span class="smaller">- luke@bodymetrix.com</span>
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 small-10 columns" id="social-btn">
        <img src="img/facebook-btn.png" alt="Facebook">
        <img src="img/twitter-btn.png" alt="Twitter">
        <img src="img/pin-btn.png" alt="Pintrest">
        <img src="img/google-btn.png" alt="Google+">
    </div>        
    <hr>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
        <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Body Metrix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="large-6 columns" id="nav-btn">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li><!--
         --><li class="not"><a href="#">About</a></li><!--
         --><li class="not"><a href="#">Contact</a></li><!--
         --><li class="not"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div><!--
```

CSS:

```
hr {
    margin:0;
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

#social-btn{    
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#contact-top-pad {    
    padding-top: 25px;    
}

.contact-top {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;    
}

.smaller {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: lighter;    
}

.logo img {
    max-width: 35%;
    min-height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.navigation { margin:0; }
```

Thanks

Comment: could you provide a **http://jsfiddle.net** please?

Comment: +1 Pedro, or a link to this site you are making so we can "Inspect Element" or something .

Comment: You haven't commented out the initial whitespace between the ul and the first li or the white-space between the end li and closing ul tag, you may also need to add padding:0 to your .navigation

Comment: added above, sites not live so cant give you a link

Comment: the `img` inside `div.logo` has a `padding-bottom` of `10`

Comment: i need the logo to have padding. plus i removed it just to see and it didnt make any difference to white space

Comment: @PedroEstrada, I'm guessing that logo is appearing on the left of the nav due to it being 6 cols within the row div

Comment: @user3087394 then that fiddle does not accurately represent your issue. I suggest fixing it please.

Comment: @user3087394 you need to provide more information as the styles and code you have provided don't look anything like your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4k3RA/

Comment: Sorry, it is now much better in the JS FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/ygfX7/4/ @Pete

Comment: @user3087394 i dont see a space http://grab.by/xiyw

Comment: @PedroEstrada Theres a space of around 2px, not much but it is still whitespace i dont want there. spread the browser page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `border-bottom` from `hr` to get rid of that small space above the options:

```
hr {
    margin:0;
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

And also add a `line-height: 100px;` to `.navigation li a` which will center the text vertically:

```
.navigation li a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 10px 10px 30px;
    line-height:100px;
}
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ygfX7/5/

Answer (score 1):

Add same `line-height` value as same value of the `li` height

```
.navigation li a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 10px 10px 30px;
    line-height:100px;
}
```

**result:** http://jsfiddle.net/ygfX7/1/